# Follow link inside JQuery click event

Tags: jquery

I have links inside `<td>`s, but I also have a click event on all `<td>`s. The code looks like this:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( 'td.event' ).click( function() {
        var eventName = prompt( 'Enter event:' );
        if ( eventName != null && eventName.length > 0 ) {
            window.location = '?event=' + eventName;
        }
    } );
} );
```

I want to simply follow the link without showing the popup if the user clicks the link, but to show the popup if the user clicks anywhere else in the `<td>`. Is this possible in JQuery?

Comment: Have you tried defining the `click` event on all the `a` elements via JQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to the end of your `document.ready` handler:

```
$( 'td.event a' ).click( function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
} );
```

Comment: The script doesn't seem to act any differently with this code. Does the event propagate from the inner-most element out or the outer-most in?

Comment: It should work. Did you put this inside the `document.ready` handler? It should be inside that handler. See demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32hXu/1/).

Comment: Sorry it did work, I just found out now that I spelled `stopPropagation()` as `stopPropogation()` which caused the script to fail silently. Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: No worries. And to answer your question: yes, it propagates up the DOM tree, from the innermost element. It's called "event bubbling".

Answer (score 3):

```
function yourFunction()
{
   var eventName = prompt( 'Enter event:' );

   if(eventName != null && eventName.length > 0) {
      window.location = '?event='+eventName;
   }
}

$('td').click(function() {
   yourFunction();
});

$('td a').click(function() {
   window.location = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

should do the trick.

Comment: This follows the link when you click on it, but the prompt still comes up. Is there some way to suppress the prompt when the link is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

It might to be helpful.

```
$("td.event a").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("td").click(function(event){
                if(!event.isPropagationStopped()) {
                    var eventName = prompt("Enter event: ");
                    if(eventName != null && eventName.length > 0) {
                        window.location = "?event=" + eventName;
                    }
                }
            });
            $("a").click(function(event){
                event.stopPropagation();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color: grey; width: 100px; height: 20px;">
                <a href="http://www.google.be">google</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```